# How to Update or Add to a Collection properly in Parallel processing (ForEach)

Tags: c#, collections, parallel-processing, thread-safety, parallel.foreach

I am trying to process a list of addresses into 2 collections; a list of addresses that meets requirements; a list of scores for each of those addresses that meets requirements.
I have several different criteria to slice and dice the addresses, but I am running into an incorrect implementation of modifying a collection during parallel processing.

For instance, I take the zip code and for each (+388k records) I determine if the Levenshtein Distance is greater or equal to a filtering value.  If it does, then add the address to the compiled list of addresses.  Then using the SET method, determine if the score for the address already exists.  If is does not, then add. Else use the score currently in the collection and update the appropriate property.

I am hitting the "Collection Has Been Modified" error and I can not think of another way to implement the solution.  I am looking for alternative ways to accomplish this.

```
private LevenshteinDistance _ld = new LevenshteinDistance();
private int _filter_zip = int.Parse(ConfigHelper.GetAppSettingByKey("filter_zip"));
public Factory ScoreAddresses(Factory model)
{
    Factory result = model;

    IList<Address> _compiledList = new List<Address>();
    IList<Scores> _compiledScores = new List<Scores>();

    ParallelLoopResult MailLoopResult = Parallel.ForEach(
        result.ALL_Addresses, factory =>
        {
            if (factory.MAIL_ZIP_CODE_NBR != null
                && factory.MAIL_ZIP_CODE_NBR.Length >= 1)
            {
                int _zipDistance = _ld.Compute(
                    result.Target_Address.MAIL_ZIP_CODE_NBR,
                    factory.MAIL_ZIP_CODE_NBR);
                if (_zipDistance <= _filter_zip)
                {
                    _compiledList.Add(factory);
                    Scores _score = new Scores();
                    _compiledScores = _score.Set(_compiledScores,
                        factory.INDIVIDUAL_ID, "Levenshtein_MAIL_ZIP_CODE_NBR",
                        _zipDistance, string.Empty, null);
                }
            }
        });
    return result;
}

public IList<Scores> Set(IList<Scores> current, int Individual_ID,
    string Score_Type, int Levenshtein, string Methaphone, decimal? other)
{
    int currentcount = current.Count();
    bool updating = false;
    IList<Scores> result = current;
    try
    {
        Scores newscore = new Scores();
        //Check if scoreing for individual already present
        Scores lookingforIndv = current.AsParallel().Where(
            p => p.INDIVIDUAL_ID == Individual_ID).FirstOrDefault();

        if (lookingforIndv != null)
        {
            newscore = lookingforIndv;
            updating = true;
        }
        else
        {
            newscore.INDIVIDUAL_ID = Individual_ID;
            updating = false;
        }
        //Add score based upon indicated score type
        switch (Score_Type)
        {
            case "Levenshtein_MAIL_ZIP_CODE_NBR":
                newscore.Levenshtein_MAIL_ZIP_CODE_NBR = Levenshtein;
                result.Add(newscore);
                break;
                //More and More Cases
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your topic is not my strong side, but you can encourage other users to help you on your issue by providing a [minimal working example]{https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example}.